# How do i add to each link the number 10 then 20 30 40 50?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is the code:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    client.DownloadFile(mainurl + i + 10, htmlFilesDirectory + "\\test\\" + i + 10 + ".html");
                }
            }
```

I need that on my hard disk the html downloaded file will be:

10.html
20.html
30.html
.
.
.
.
.
.
100.html

The mainurl is something like "www.test.test&&num="
So when doing this in the download html: mainurl + i + 10
It should be like

```
www.test.test&&num=10 
www.test.test&&num=20
www.test.test&&num= 30

.
.
.
.
www.test.test&&num=100
```

But in fact the way the code is now im getting on the hard disk many html files instead only 10 html files.

I should see on my hard disk 10 html files:

```
www.test.test&&num=10
www.test.test&&num=20
www.test.test&&num=30

10.html
20.html
30.html
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace your loop with this:

```
for (int i = 10; i <= 100; i += 10)
{
  client.DownloadFile(mainurl + i, htmlFilesDirectory + "\\test\\" + i + ".html");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Buddy check your loop you need to increment of 10 but you just do the increment of 1 therefore your loop run 100 times instead of 10